# Beamer, itemize and \hfill

Tags: beamer, horizontal-alignment, itemize

As you can see in the image below, the `EndOfLine`s are not correctly right aligned: The alignment using `\hfill` is different for an `\item` followed by an `itemize` environment compared to an `\item` followed by another `\item` or nothing.

Is that a slight bug in Beamer? How shall I correct this, at least locally?

[image: Not aligned!]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item Item 1 \hfill EndOfLine
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Subitem
    \end{itemize}
\item Item 2 \hfill EndOfLine
\item Item 3 \hfill EndOfLine
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Subitem 
    \end{itemize}
\item Item 4 \hfill EndOfLine
\end{itemize}
\end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try giving a blank line before every

```
\begin{itemize}
```

or a % or // after EndofLine. This seem to work!

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item Item 1 \hfill EndOfLine

\begin{itemize}
\item Subitem
\end{itemize}
\item Item 2 \hfill EndOfLine
\item Item 3 \hfill EndOfLine

\begin{itemize}
\item Subitem 
\end{itemize}
\item Item 4 \hfill EndOfLine
\end{itemize}
\end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It indeed works. I prefer the solution with `%` since I find it the least intrusive in the code. Before accepting your answer, I'll wait for a potential answer on whether it is considered a bug or not. And whether there may be a fix that does not require to change the code, say using a package or some magic command in the preamble.